# 4th Isomorphism Theorem applied to normalizers

Tags: group-theory

I'm reading a proof showing a proper subgroup Q of p-group P is contained in it's normalizer.

It applies the 4th Isomorphism Theorem to assert $\frac{Q}{Z(P)} < N_{\frac{P}{Z(P)}}(\frac{Q}{Z(P)})$ implies $Q < N_P(Q)$. How is this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $N_{P/Z(P)}(Q/Z(P))=N_P(Q)/Z(P)$.

(And proper inclusions remain proper under lattice correspondence.)